# Spring Boot Application gets stuck at HikariPool-1 - Starting

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am developing a Spring Boot App for university and it's required to be deployed to AWS or Google Cloud. I chose AWS and I deployed my app on an EC2 ubuntu instance. The problem is when I run the app it gets stuck after "HikariPool-1 - Starting...", while it works perfectly fine on the local machine. This is the build message:

[image: build message.]

Also my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/comics
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
server.port=80
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=lazy
```

As you can see, I've tried some solutions I found on similar questions, such as adding these lines:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=lazy
```

These should make the startup time faster but I don't really think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try deploying your app to [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) (this uses EC2).  There is an example of deploying a Spring app that to Elastic Beanstalk in the AWS Github. That is, this tutorial guides you through creating an AWS application that uses Spring Boot. After you develop the application, you will learn how to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk.

[Creating your first AWS Java web application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_first_project)

Comment: I switched to Google Cloud in the meantime so I don't know if your solution would've helped. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: My solution is for AWS - not other Cloud providers